# Return the column heading for the column containing the largest value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table as shown below.

[image]

I want to find the column heading for the column containing the largest value.

If was trying to find a value in a single column I could do:

```
=COLUMN((INDEX(TableName[Col],MATCH(M22,TableName[Col],1))))
```

Where `M22` is the largest value (in this case, assumed already known to be the largest in the column, having been determined outside of this formula; I'm showing a cell reference to not muddy the illustration formula with the determination of the largest value).

So what I am trying to do is to find the largest number in my table. I then want to see what member of staff got it.  Is there a way I could do this looking at multiple columns?

Comment: You need to find a single value (as M22 in your single column example) or the largest value?

Comment: I need to find the column of the largest value. The M22 in my example was a column holding the largest value.

Comment: So in your example, the answer is Bob?

Comment: I tried to clarify the question based on your comments.  If this is incorrect, please change it to reflect what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MATCH` only supports one dimensional input ranges. You can use this formula:

`=MAX(IF(B2:C17=E1,COLUMN(B2:C17),""))`
This is an array formula, so press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after entering it.

[image]

Comment: This is not my question, but I would just like to know what does CTRL+SHIFT+Enter do exactly?

Comment: Then what is your question? It returns that your value is in the second column (B). More about array formulas: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: I meant the original question was not asked by me :)